# BASH script modifications for free space monitoring purpose

Tags: bash

unable to make modifications to fit into my enviroment, this is the check_disc function, but not working correctly in my enviroment where disc is attached through /dev/mapper/ so i have 
for exmaple /dev/mapper/debian-var instead of /var.

Function from BASH script:

```
function check_disks {

    THOLD=$1;
    DISK_ERROR="";

    # df -kl is the most portable options for df 

    MOUNTS=`df -lk | grep -v devfs | grep -v none | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $6}'`;
    for MOUNT in $MOUNTS; do
        PERCENT=`df -kl $MOUNT | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/\%//'`;
        if [ $PERCENT -gt $THOLD ]; then
            DISK_ERROR="$DISK_ERROR    Volume '$MOUNT' is at $PERCENT% usage.\n";
        fi
    done
    if [ -n "$DISK_ERROR" ]; then
        echo -en "ERROR: The following volumes have exceeded the allowable threshold of $THOLD% usage.\n$DISK_ERROR";
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    fi

}
```

Output of df -kl cmd:

```
df -kl
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/debian-root
                       1919048    493616   1327948  28% /
tmpfs                 18717148        12  18717136   1% /lib/init/rw
udev                     10240       784      9456   8% /dev
tmpfs                 18717148         0  18717148   0% /dev/shm
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1       241116     23679    204989  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/debian-home
                       3842104   2681264    965668  74% /home
/dev/mapper/debian-tmp
                       4805760    366228   4195412   9% /tmp
/dev/mapper/debian-usr
                       3842104   1816200   1830732  50% /usr
/dev/mapper/debian-var
                     377857560 183429768 175233732  52% /var
```

This line should be changed i guess:

```
MOUNTS=`df -lk | grep -v devfs | grep -v none | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $6}'`;
```

But not sure how. Anyone can give me a hand?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a portability option on `df` that keeps the output in one line per volume :

```
   -P, --portability
          use the POSIX output format
```

I think changing

```
MOUNTS=`df -lk | grep -v devfs | grep -v none | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $6}'`
```

to

```
MOUNTS=`df -lkP | grep -v devfs | grep -v none | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $6}'`
```

would help.

FYI, here is an example of the output difference :

```
$ df -lk | grep -B1 /var
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var
                   4062912   1900724   1952476  50% /var
$ df -lkP | grep /var
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var   4062912   1900748   1952452      50% /var
```

Comment: sure, main question is answered, it would be handy if i can explude /home directory since that may cause alerts if gets full but thats not really importat when comes to server stability. Thats just btw :}

Comment: just add `| grep -v /home` at the end of the `MOUNTS` command and this will get rid of `/home`. If that is what you mean.